# how can I set all folders to show file version at an OS level?

Tags: windows, directory

I'm managing a lot of dll's and one thing I have to do constantly when copying them around is to turn on the file version attribute display in the folder where my dll's are. I'd like to set this globally to my machine so I do not have to set this for each individual folder I work in.

Ideally I would like to find an administrative template in an existing group policy object and make a change there. The last time I went hunting for that option in the policy management editor I was unable to find it.

I had forgotten about this annoyance until i've had to make this attribute change about 7 times today when debugging and doing winmerge comparisons against some older backups while trying to find a bug.

If anyone knows a workaround let me know. It would be great if the workaround can apply to xp and 7 both. I'm sure there is something out there to do this easy but I have just not found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/470867/156043) to a similar question on Super User. You just select the `File Version` column instead of the `Pages` column before appying the new view to all folders.